# how to resolve error while writing nunit test case for Application.Current.FindResource() in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am writing test case for a class, having Application.Current.FindResource()method. But while passing through above code in i am getting error like "ObjectNotInitialized".
Following is the code:-`public void ContactListViewModel()

```
{
    var app = Application.Current;
    var default_Flag = (DrawingImage) app.FindResource("Unknown_Flag");
}
```

and following is the error, i am getting:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

please, tell me how to write test case for this method

Comment: Use TryFindResource, instead exception null will be returned.

Comment: We *don't* write unit tests for the UI. If you insist on testing your user interface, then you should use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would nuance the comment of Sheridan as an answer:
In WPF you test your UI by testing your ViewModel (this is one of the reason why MVVM is so important for a WPF project). If you want more than that, yes you can use the [UI automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551(v=vs.110).aspx).

As often here, you can't test your class because it is coupled to the Application. (ie: you are stuck because of your call to Application.Current)

Now imagine if instead of this direct call, you inject (via a parameter) the current application as an interface. Then this interface could be mock, thus your class will become testable (your dependency will be inverted).

In conclusion you actually have a way to test that even without refactoring, using [MS fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx). But I give it to you just as an information, I highly discourage you to use it, especially if you are a beginner for unit testing. It is more usefull when you want to test legacy code.